# return View() returns an error when passing a variable storing the path name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is probably a very straightforward question. But i building an MVC app and for reasons not needed to explain here i don't think i am storing a path to a view in a variable.

```
var pathToView = "~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml";
```

I am then calling this view like so from another controller:

```
return View(pathToView);
```

This returns a Server Application error stating that a view cannot be found.

However, if I pass the following:

```
return View(string.Format("{0}", pathToView));
```

This works fine.

What is the reason that i cannot pass the variable?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the exact code im using, with the faulting return statement commented out.

```
public ActionResult Returned()
    {
        //At this point Session["viewToReturn"] = "~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml"
        var view = Session["viewToReturn"];
        return View(string.Format("{0}",view));

        //return View(view);
    }
```

Comment: What does `String.Format` return?

Comment: IIRC, views are not referenced by an application path (i.e. `"~/something..."`), but rather the name of the view (`"ViewName"` above) will be searched for by the ViewEngine in a bunch of specific locations.

Comment: what does your view page looks like ? have you declared a type of model for it ?

Comment: no model is declared. The view uses _Layout.cshtml as its master. The view im trying to return simply contains several @section sectionName { } definitions.

Comment: Since your parentheses are mismatched, your code won't compile. Please paste exactly your code as it may give a clue like you are actually calling a different overload of `View()` than you think.

Comment: edited the mismatched parentheses! Added the actual code. The above code is working when using string.Format but not when just using the view variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get items from `Session` using indexers, they are retrieved as `object`.

This in turn means that with the call to

```
View(view)
```

`view` is an `object`, the incorrect overload of `View` is selected:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    object model
)
```

and the `view` is interpreted as the model, not the view name. Now `View` is looking for a view that matches the name of the controller method as no view name was specified.

To correct this, a cast is required:

```
var view = (string)Session["viewToReturn"];
```

and now the expected overload is invoked.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the explanation. I was checking the type with view.GetType() which was returning System.String which was confusing me.